# create an excel report based off 2 list

Tags: excel

im facing this issue whereby i have 2 seperate list reports 1 of them contains details of warehousing inwards quantity, while the other contains details of warehousing outwards quantity. These lists contains basic details like item models, date and quantity.

now the problem've is I would like to create a 3rd list, that concludes each end of day warehouse movement. What is the best way to create this 3rd list given that i'm able to utilize accessDB for ease of data management as well ?

Comment: by the way my end of day movement should conclude for every single day, even if there are no inwards / outwards movement at a certain date. the date should still appear.

Comment: You can use SELECT queries with JOINs within an Excel workbook. http://analystcave.com/excel-using-sql-in-vba-on-excel-data/

Comment: Power Query (Get & Transform Data) would handle this easily.